# Why does double pipe give syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I do something like this on the console:

```
foo = "truthy"
bar = foo || "baz"
```

It works as expected. `bar` is assigned the value of the variable on the left hand side of the double pipes if it is truthy, otherwise the value of the right hand side variable.

In my Rails app I have something like this:

```
def fetch_feed_info
    info_loader = RSSInfoLoader.new(url)
    title = info_loader.title || ""
    website = info_loader.website || ""
end
```

However, this gives a syntax error both when running tests or creating an instance of the class in the Rails console. The error is:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Can anyone explain to me why?

**Stack trace**

```
/Users/ricco/Sites/RoR/rss-plough/app/models/feed.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
website = info_loader.website || ""
                                   ^
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/ricco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/ricco/Sites/RoR/rss-plough/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/ricco/Sites/RoR/rss-plough/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/ricco/Sites/RoR/rss-plough/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from test/unit/rssinfoloader_test.rb:1:in `require'
from test/unit/rssinfoloader_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

The function that fails:

```
def fetch_feed_info
    info_loader = RSSInfoLoader.new(url)
    title = info_loader.title || ""
    website = info_loader.website || ""
end
```

Comment: I think your syntax error is not in this piece of code. It might be hanging quote from some other line.

Comment: The syntax error isn't in this code unless you didn't copy it correctly - can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: can you provide more info please, might be good to look at your feed.rb

Comment: I removed the function with the syntax errors and ran my test. This time I got no syntax errors. Then I gradually rewrote the function from scratch and ran my test again and again to find out what was causing the problem. Now it works! Very odd. It must have been a stray character of some sort.